# Is there any date when sensenet 7 will be launched?

Tags: sensenet

As an opensource .Net ECMS, Sensenet seems to have a lot of features, anyway in their developer blog, it seems they are working for an SN7 version with more goodlooking UI.

Do you have any info, when it will be released?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming; rather, the OP should contact Sensenet directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we are working on SN7 for some time now. Part of that work is to partition this huge product into smaller components. The plan is to release the core layer, the Content Repository (without UI) on github soon. After that the rest will follow gradually, as optional packages. The main focus now is on the platform with an easy-to-use client api.

Comment: The core layer of Sense/Net 7 (called SenseNet.Services) is released (currently in beta), the next layer (WebPages, the one that contains the admin UI) will follow soon.
https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet